# create a string list from a generic class and and apply TrueForAll on that list

Tags: c#, list, generics

Here i have a generic class called `"GoodBuffer"`.I've created a list of string from that class.The class has a generic list as property on which i can operate different method.I want to implement `TrueForAll` method on that list to find if any string member of that list ends with "ball".So i created a `CheckEndsWithBall` method and implemented `TrueForAll` on the internal list.But i am getting the following error :

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Endswith' and no extension
>   method 'Endswith' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

GoodBuffer class :

```
class GoodBuffer<T>
{
    List<T> bufferList;
    public GoodBuffer()
    {
        bufferList = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T val)
    {
        bufferList.Add(val);
    }

    public int Size()
    {
        return bufferList.Count();
    }
    public bool CheckEndsWithBall()
    {          
        return bufferList.TrueForAll(b => b.EndsWith("ball"));
    }

}
```

main functin :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = new GoodBuffer<string>();

    s.Add("redball");
    s.Add("blue");

    Console.WriteLine(s.Size());

    Console.WriteLine(s.CheckEndsWithBall());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Capital W in EndsWith. Also you're going to have to tell the compiler it's a string somehow... or deal with it when `T` isn't a string.

Comment: T is string as i have enforced it to be string while instantiating GoodBuffer class.I changed small "w" to capital "W". problem still persists !

Comment: T is not string. T is generic, therefore, does not have such method..

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ok, but when i instantiated the class i passed "string" as type in 

var s = new GoodBuffer<string>(); can u please explain ?

Comment: @AL-zami: Yeah, but at the time of compiling, how does it know whether it's a string? Also, when you denote `<T>`, you're saying **anything** will be supported. This includes `double`, `int`, `bool`, `object` as well as `string`. In fact, look at your code and what you're trying to do. You define the `T` as a string in a **totally different part of code**. You're completely misunderstanding the concept of `T` and generics in general.

Comment: @code4life i am completely new to c sharp. I've started it only a couple of weeks back.It would be better if shed some light on the matter :)

Comment: @AL-zami: unfortunately SO is not the place to get tutoring on this. It's more geared towards solving well-defined problems/questions. You really need to hit MSDN and start with the basics, my friend.

Comment: @AL-zami: The thing about generics is that you are saying that it works for all types. Your code needs to work correctly for `GoodBuffer<int>`, `GoodBuffer<object>` and anything else. So when you are using objects of type `T` they can only use the methods of `object`, the only ones that are guaranteed to be on the object. If you want `GoodBuffer` to always work on strings then don't make it generic, just change `bufferList` to be of type `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need explicitly convert your `T` to string. Try this code:

```
public bool CheckEndsWithBall()
{          
    return bufferList.TrueForAll(b => b.ToString().EndsWith("ball"));
}
```

UPD: When compiler see `GoodBuffer` class it does know nothing about `T`. And you telling to compiler: "execute method on T". How can compiler be sure that this method exists? Generics in c# are not same as templates in C++. Generic class will be compiled into "open type" without looking at further usage.
However, you can use type constraint like this:

```
public interface ICanCheckEndsWith
{
    bool EndsWith(string end);
}

public class StringWrapper : ICanCheckEndsWith
{
    public string String { get; set; }

    public bool EndsWith(string end)
    {
        return String.EndsWith(end);
    }
}

public class GoodBuffer<T> where T : ICanCheckEndsWith
{
    private List<T> buffer = new List<T>();

    public bool CheckEndsWithBall()
    {
        return buffer.TrueForAll(b => b.EndsWith("ball"));
    }
}
```

Comment: but when i instantiated the class i passed "string" as type in var s = new GoodBuffer<string>(); can u please explain ?

Comment: great explanation .thnx a lot ;)

Comment: what  does "where T" means ?

Comment: @AL-zami it's a [type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)